# Clarification on existing pygame sidescroller

Tags: python, camera, pygame

I am trying to get a side-scroller going using pygame and I have been studying the following program but need a few points clarified:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import pygame, platform
platform.architecture()

from pygame import *

WIN_WIDTH = 800
WIN_HEIGHT = 640
HALF_WIDTH = int(WIN_WIDTH / 2)
HALF_HEIGHT = int(WIN_HEIGHT / 2)

DISPLAY = (WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)
DEPTH = 32
FLAGS = 0
CAMERA_SLACK = 30

def main():
    global cameraX, cameraY
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY, FLAGS, DEPTH)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Use arrows to move!")
    timer = pygame.time.Clock()

    up = down = left = right = running = False
    bg = Surface((32,32))
    bg.convert()
    bg.fill(Color("#000000"))
    entities = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player = Player(32, 32)
    platforms = []

    x = y = 0
    level = [
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                    PPPPPPPPPPP           P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P    PPPPPPPP                              P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                          PPPPPPP         P",
        "P                 PPPPPP                   P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P         PPPPPPP                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                     PPPPPP               P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P   PPPPPPPPPPP                            P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                 PPPPPPPPPPP              P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",]
    # build the level
    for row in level:
        for col in row:
            if col == "P":
                p = Platform(x, y)
                platforms.append(p)
                entities.add(p)
            if col == "E":
                e = ExitBlock(x, y)
                platforms.append(e)
                entities.add(e)
            x += 32
        y += 32
        x = 0

    total_level_width  = len(level[0])*32
    total_level_height = len(level)*32

    #COMPLEX_CAMERA???
    camera = Camera(complex_camera, total_level_width, total_level_height)

    entities.add(player)

    while 1:
        timer.tick(60)

        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == QUIT: raise SystemExit, "QUIT"
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_ESCAPE:
                raise SystemExit, "ESCAPE"
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_UP:
                up = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_DOWN:
                down = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_LEFT:
                left = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_SPACE:
                running = True

            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_UP:
                up = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_DOWN:
                down = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_LEFT:
                left = False

        # draw background
        for y in range(32):
            for x in range(32):
                screen.blit(bg, (x * 32, y * 32))

        camera.update(player)

        # update player, draw everything else
        player.update(up, down, left, right, running, platforms)
        for e in entities:
            screen.blit(e.image, camera.apply(e))

        pygame.display.update()

class Camera(object):

    #CAMERA_FUNC???
    def __init__(self, camera_func, width, height):
        self.camera_func = camera_func
        self.state = Rect(0, 0, width, height)

    def apply(self, target):
        return target.rect.move(self.state.topleft)

    def update(self, target):
        self.state = self.camera_func(self.state, target.rect)

def simple_camera(camera, target_rect):

    #UNDERLINE???
    l, t, _, _ = target_rect
    _, _, w, h = camera
    return Rect(-l+HALF_WIDTH, -t+HALF_HEIGHT, w, h)

def complex_camera(camera, target_rect):
    l, t, _, _ = target_rect
    _, _, w, h = camera
    l, t, _, _ = -l+HALF_WIDTH, -t+HALF_HEIGHT, w, h

    l = min(0, l)                           # stop scrolling at the left edge
    l = max(-(camera.width-WIN_WIDTH), l)   # stop scrolling at the right edge
    t = max(-(camera.height-WIN_HEIGHT), t) # stop scrolling at the bottom
    t = min(0, t)                           # stop scrolling at the top
    return Rect(l, t, w, h)

class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

class Player(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.xvel = 0
        self.yvel = 0
        self.onGround = False
        self.image = Surface((32,32))
        self.image.fill(Color("#0000FF"))
        self.image.convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)

    def update(self, up, down, left, right, running, platforms):
        if up:
            # only jump if on the ground
            if self.onGround: self.yvel -= 10
        if down:
            pass
        if running:
            self.xvel = 12
        if left:
            self.xvel = -8
        if right:
            self.xvel = 8
        if not self.onGround:
            # only accelerate with gravity if in the air
            self.yvel += 0.3
            # max falling speed
            if self.yvel > 100: self.yvel = 100
        if not(left or right):
            self.xvel = 0
        # increment in x direction
        self.rect.left += self.xvel
        # do x-axis collisions
        self.collide(self.xvel, 0, platforms)
        # increment in y direction
        self.rect.top += self.yvel
        # assuming we're in the air
        self.onGround = False;
        # do y-axis collisions
        self.collide(0, self.yvel, platforms)

    def collide(self, xvel, yvel, platforms):
        for p in platforms:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, p):
                if isinstance(p, ExitBlock):
                    pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(QUIT))
                if xvel > 0:
                    self.rect.right = p.rect.left
                    print "collide right"
                if xvel < 0:
                    self.rect.left = p.rect.right
                    print "collide left"
                if yvel > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = p.rect.top
                    self.onGround = True
                    self.yvel = 0
                if yvel < 0:
                    self.rect.top = p.rect.bottom


class Platform(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.image = Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.convert()
        self.image.fill(Color("#DDDDDD"))
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)

    def update(self):
        pass

class ExitBlock(Platform):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Platform.__init__(self, x, y)
        self.image.fill(Color("#0033FF"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

First off, what is 'complex_camera' in this line of code:

```
camera = Camera(complex_camera, total_level_width, total_level_height)
```

Is complex_camera a call to the function? If so, isn't the function 'complex_camera' expecting the camera's rect and the player's rect? Why are there no parenthesis and no arguments being passed to the function?

Perhaps on a related note, in this block of code found in the constructor for Camera:

```
self.camera_func = camera_func
```

Why is there a 'camera_func' property when it's never used in the program?

My last question is in the following block of code:

```
def simple_camera(camera, target_rect):
    l, t, _, _ = target_rect
    _, _, w, h = camera
    return Rect(-l+HALF_WIDTH, -t+HALF_HEIGHT, w, h)
```

Can you explain the meaning of the underscores? I send out a message of appreciation in advanced for clearing these points up for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: `complex_camera` is a function returning a rect
and it's not a call, it's just passing that function to the `Camera` object.

```
self.camera_func = camera_func
```

in this case `self.camera_func` will be `complex_camera`.
In this way when the `update` method of `Camera` will be called:

```
def update(self, target):
    self.state = self.camera_func(self.state, target.rect)
```

`self.state` will be equal to the output of the `complex_camera` function called with `self.state` and `target.rect` arguments

```
self.state = complex_camera(self.state, target.rect)
```

2:

```
def simple_camera(camera, target_rect):
    l, t, _, _ = target_rect
```

`target_rect` is (should be) a 4-elements tuple

```
l, t, _, _ = target_rect
```

this line tells python to "unpack" the tuple.
`l` will be equal to the first element of the tuple (in this case the "left" property of the rect)
`t` will be equal to the second.(in this case the "top" property of the rect)

`_` just means this property isn't being taken in consideration; but since `target_rect` is expected to be a 4-element tuple, then unpacking it should provide 4 variables, and not only 2.

for example:

```
my_tuple = ('a', 'b', 'c')
first, second, third = my_tuple
```

now `first = 'a', second = 'b', third = 'c'`

if you only wants to use first and third you will do:

```
first, _, third = my_tuple
```

sorry for my bad english

Comment: Thank you so much 'nonsensei' for that clear explanation. Can you tell me why was the Camera constructor passed 'complex_camera' as a function rather than written as a class method of Camera?

Comment: It looks like the `Camera` class is meant to be part of a library and the user can provide the update function without changing `Camera` class.